# Jetson nano could not install PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying hard to install PyQt5 in my Jetson nano. However, there is one thing always annoys me.
here's the feedback message.

```
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for sip
      Failed to build sip
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I've tried `sudo pip3 install pyqt5` and it gave me

```
compilation terminated.
            error: command '/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for sip
      Failed to build sip
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`. It worked but when I imported PyQt5 by `from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui` or `from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal`, it gave me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/llw/Desktop/project/ture file/save_pointcloud.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyqtgraph/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .colors import palette
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyqtgraph/colors/palette.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..Qt import QtGui
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyqtgraph/Qt/__init__.py", line 155, in <module>
    import PyQt5.QtCore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore
```

How do I fix this problem? Any suggestions or ideas could be a help.

Thank you.